# Python check if a dataframe single contains contains a keyword

Tags: python, dataframe

- I have a value in my df `NEFT fm Principal Focused Multi`.
- I have a list of words containing keywords like `NEFT, neft`. So, if the above string of DF contains `NEFT` word, I want to add a new column and mark it as `True`.
- Sample Input

[image]

- I was trying

```
for index, row in ldf_first_page.iterrows():
    row.str.lower().isin(llst_transaction_keywords)
```

- But it is trying to check the exact keyword, and I am looking for something like `contains`.

Comment: No images. please provide data as a code (preferably) or text. Refer to stackoverflow guidance  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but what I understand you want to add a column for every key word and set only the value true at the rows that contain that key word? I would do

First read the data

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

example_data = """
Date,Narration,Other
31/03/21, blabla, 1
12/2/20, here neft in, 2
10/03/19, NEFT is in, 3
9/04/18, ok, 4
11/08/21, oki cha , 5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(example_data))
```

Now loop over the keywords and see if there are matches. Note that I have imported the *re* module to allow for INGNORECASE

```
transaction_keywords = ["neft", "cha"]

for keyword in transaction_keywords:
    mask = df["Narration"].str.contains(keyword, regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if mask.any():
        df[keyword] = mask
```

The result looks like this:

```
       Date      Narration  Other   neft    cha
0  31/03/21         blabla      1  False  False
1   12/2/20   here neft in      2   True  False
2  10/03/19     NEFT is in      3   True  False
3   9/04/18             ok      4  False  False
4  11/08/21       oki cha       5  False   True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `any()`.

```
for index, row in ldf_first_page.iterrows():
    row.str.lower().any(llst_transaction_keywords)
```

Comment: throws an error ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for index, row in ldf_first_page.iterrows():
    if llst_transaction_keywords in row:
          return True
```

Comment: facing an error ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df["new_col"] = np.where(df["Narration"].str.lower().str.contains("neft"), True, False)
```

Comment: i don't have "Narration" as a header, as you can see in the question above. ```KeyError: 'Narration'```

Comment: @donny do ```print(ldf_first_page.columns)``` and tell me what it returns